# How do I add a new article in Liferay 6.1 programmatically?

Tags: liferay

In liferay 6.0 you can use

```
JournalArticleServiceUtil.addArticle
```

But now there are some new arguments in this method:

```
long classNameId, long classPK
```

What does its mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For adding journal articles, it looks like you can pass 0 for both values.

It appears it was added for your convince as a 3rd party developer to find articles created for your application quicker. See, http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-16960.

Comment: I encountered the same issue migration some Liferay code today and indeed the API has changed (again, why do they keep doing that) and after debugging through EditArticleAction is does indeed seem that you can just use 0 twice as that's what they internally do too.